# How do you use Vueform Multiselect with Tailwind

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

In the documentation of [VueForm Multiselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vueform/multiselect#styling-with-tailwind-css) I see that it says "To use with Tailwind you need to import images to tailwind and then the theme in your component".

Which is fine, but the documentation says nothing else? I can't seem to grasp how do you **use** it with Tailwind and there's no information about this here or on the internet at all.

Comment: here you have very good examples of VueForm Multiselect and Tailwind https://jsfiddle.net/q6Lnpr7a/

Comment: Hey@PedroBarreto I don't know if it's me, but I can't see anything Tailwind related in that fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution

```
.multiselect__select {
  @apply <tailwind-classes-here>
}
```

https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/287

Hints

check Multiselect styles section here:

https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/blob/next/src/Multiselect.vue

to get know which styles you want to override.